# Why does Pandas Dataframe.where method return NaN after calling dropna()?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.dropna(inplace=True)

filter1 = df['col1'] == 'some_value'
filter2 = df['col2'] == 'some_other_value'

df.where(filter1 & filter2, inplace=True)

df.head()

     localCountry localState remoteCountry remoteState  ... col1 col2 col3 num_samples
1250          NaN        NaN           NaN         NaN  ...           NaN           NaN            NaN         NaN
1251          NaN        NaN           NaN         NaN  ...           NaN           NaN            NaN         NaN
```

I thought `dropna()` would remove all rows that contained at least one `NaN`. Why is there NaN in the result here? A misunderstanding on my part for sure, but I haven't been able to logic out why this is the case after using `dropna` prior to the `where` method.

Edit for others:

The `where()` method replaces the values where the condition passed is false. If you don't supply a default, it will replace them with NaN. It is not just a query to return rows where both conditions are met.

> Dataframe.where
>
> Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with
>   corresponding value from other. If cond is callable, it is computed on
>   the Series/DataFrame and should return boolean Series/DataFrame or
>   array. The callable must not change input Series/DataFrame (though
>   pandas doesn’t check it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you are missing the default value of [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for setting rows not matched  by any of the conditions (`other`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['some_value','some_value','aaa','dd'],
                   'col2':['some_other_value','dd','some_other_value', 'bb'],
                   'col3':list('abcd')})
print (df)
         col1              col2  col3
0  some_value  some_other_value     0
1  some_value                dd     1
2         aaa  some_other_value     2
3          dd                bb     3

filter1 = df['col1'] == 'some_value'
filter2 = df['col2'] == 'some_other_value'
df.where(filter1 & filter2, other=np.nan, inplace=True)
print (df)
0  some_value  some_other_value    a
1         NaN               NaN  NaN
2         NaN               NaN  NaN
3         NaN               NaN  NaN
```

If you change the replacement value:

```
df.where(filter1 & filter2, other='val', inplace=True)
         col1              col2 col3
0  some_value  some_other_value    a
1         val               val  val
2         val               val  val
3         val               val  val
```

If you want to filter the rows, then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[filter1 & filter2]
```

Comment: I totally misunderstood the `where()` method. This makes total sense, thank you! I didn't notice that it also replaces the value where the condition is false. I was expecting it to just return rows where both conditions are met.

`Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other. If cond is callable, it is computed on the Series/DataFrame and should return boolean Series/DataFrame or array. The callable must not change input Series/DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).`